# SSRS - Repeat a rectangle based on a value returned in a query

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a requirement to print tokens using SSRS. The user will be asked to enter in the no of tokens they need and also the seed token number.

So for ex:

```
Enter No of Tokens: 5
Enter Seed No: 100
```

The SSRS report should then generate 5 tokens (appearing like a rectangle; imagine a ticket) and within each token will be a number (TOK000100) which will increase to (TOK000104).

```
================================
|   Token No: TOK000100         |
|                               |
================================
================================
|   Token No: TOK000101         |
|                               |
================================
================================
|   Token No: TOK000102         |
|                               |
================================
================================
|   Token No: TOK000103         |
|                               |
================================
================================
|   Token No: TOK000104         |
|                               |
================================
```

I use SSRS occasionally so I wouldn't describe myself as an expert and I'm looking for ideas on how I can go about achieving this? The two inputs ie No of Tokens and Seed No I can retrieve using a FetchXml (or SQL) query. But then how do I go about repeating the rectangles based on the no. of tokens retrieved? My dataset will contain just one record with 2 fields ie. NO of Tokens and Seed Value.

Alternatively, is there a way to create a dynamic dataset and insert into it as many rows as the No of Tokens value and then insert into each row the number TOK000100 to 104 and then get the rectangle to repeat for the dynamic dataset records? (like you would create a temp table in SQL) Is this even possible in SSRS?

Comment: How high a value could the `token` parameter have?

Comment: Does there need to be anything else in the token box? Should there be spaces between said token boxes? Is there anything else on the report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo don't say what version of SQL you are using so this should work with most versions. It's a bit of a hack to generate a sequence of numbers but it's good for up to about maybe 2000 numbers.

Create a dataset
Set the dataset query to something like

```
-- DECLARE @Tokens int = 5 -- uncomment these lines fort testing
-- DECLARE @Seed int = 100

SELECT TOP (@Tokens) 
        TokenNumber = @Seed -1 +  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
    FROM sys.all_objects 
    ORDER BY TokenNumber
```

Then add a table to your report and set the dataset property to the dataset you just created. You can add columns and rows as required .. You will then get one row (or as many detail rows as you have added) per token.